# django complex queryset annotation

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to add to a queryset some statistic data calculated at each user's page request to display in a large table. The annotate method might be the best choice but I'm stuck at merging created querysets to a single one for easier manipulation in the template. The queryset type is preferred to sort data.

Following is the extremely simplified principle of my application. The template and models must not be touched because it's clearly the result I want. The data sorting by column is not implemented in this example.

Here are the models:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Vote(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    accept = models.BooleanField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    censored = models.BooleanField()
```

Here's the view:

```
def summaryView(request):
    …
    contexte['poll_list'] = «insert code here»
    …
    return render_to_response('summary.html, contexte)
```

Here's the template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Poll question
      </th>
      <th>
        Number of votes
      </th>
      <th>
        Number of uncensored "yes" votes
      </th>
      <th>
        Number of censored votes
      </th>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for poll in poll_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ poll.question }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ poll.numUncensoredYesVotes }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ poll.numCensoredVotes }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The difficulty is to create the number of uncensored "yes" votes annotation. The Count() aggregation function doesn't accept filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement I would add two more fields in the Poll models it will make faster sql queries. Normally in theses cases selection will be more frequent than insertion. So this will give more performance improvement to your project.

```
from django.db import models


class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    num_censored_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    num_uncensored_yes_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


class Vote(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    accept = models.BooleanField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    censored = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        models.Model.save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
        poll = self.poll

        if self.censored:
            poll.num_censored_votes += 1
            poll.save()

        elif self.accept:
            poll.num_uncensored_yes_votes += 1
            poll.save()
```

This can be also implemented using signals.

Comment: I was thinking about to use the database like this but hoped to avoid this. Anyway that is the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this in python with 3 queries (just manually join the querysets in python), but here's how you can do it with one query:
If the Poll QuerySet you need to annotate is generated by query1, one solution is

```
contexte['poll_list'] = Poll.objects.raw(
    ' select A.*, B.numcensoredvotes, C.numuncensoredyesvotes from 
    ( query1 ) A left join (query2) B on A.id = B.poll_id
    left join (query3) C on A.id = C.poll_id' )
```

Where query2 and query3 are the aggregate queries. 
You can access the query of a queryset the following way:

```
poll_list = Poll.objects.filter(...)
poll_list.query.get_initial_alias()
(query1,q1param) = poll_list.query.sql_with_params()
```

you can do this for the aggregate queries (query2 and query3 above) as well or just write them by hand.

See also http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/1dgz97/annotating_a_queryset_with_a_nontrivial_left/ for a related scenario where a non-trivial queryset annotation is performed.